# Can I drive a motor directly with GPIO pins?

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi, gpio, 3.3v

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero with a DC motor attached (directly) to gpio. According to the Raspberry Pi Foundation:

> The operating voltage of the GPIO pins is 3.3v with a maximum current draw of 16mA. This means that we can safely power one or two LEDs (Light Emitting Diodes) from a single GPIO pin, via a resistor.

But when I enable that GPIO pin, the motor doesn't spin. It only spins if I nudge it in the right direction. And even then, it will only spin for about 0.5-1 rotation (unless I push hard; then it spins for a few seconds). I don't have a motor hat or anything.

**The questions are: Why can't I drive a motor directly with a GPIO pin? And what are possible solutions in a resource limited location?**

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's some additional information:
These motors are from a poorly built drone from a sketchy company. They don't offer any info for replacing parts. I don't know the rating of the motor. I'm going to find out more about the batteries as soon as I can.

I don't have any MOSFETs to connect, and I am in a remote location currently, so amazon can't ship, and there are no stores for miles.

I do not have a soldering iron so I am going hot glue to hold connections together. However, I am positive that the wires are securely connected to the gpio, because I have tested them with a multimeter.

Comment: What is the current rating on the motor? Motors pull significantly more current when they are stationary (locked rotor) or spinning slowly. If a motor is rated for 15 mA running @ 1000 RPM, then it likely pulls better than 50 mA loacked rotor.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I don't really know. I scrapped this from a poorly built drone from a sketchy company. They don't offer any info for replacing parts. Is there anywhere on the motor I could find this? It's very small, and it has a shiny metal body with nothing indented or written on it.

Comment: Don't directly connect motors to GPIO pins. Just don't do it.

Comment: @Andyaka Should I include a diode or transistor? I just realized that once the motor is turned off but still spinning, it could be a generator that sends voltage back into the board...

Comment: Maybe not. The motors voltage isn't going to be higher than the battery voltage on the drone but this doesn't give you any information about the current rating. I wouldn't try to run the motor directly from a GPIO. There is no use in damaging your Pi to run the motor. Do you have access to any MOSFETs?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I don't have any MOSFETs, but I do have some NPN and PNP transistors.

Comment: Try the circuit suggested by jwh20 below but use two AA batteries instead of the 12 V source or use the 3.3 V from the Pi. The diode will also be necessary to prevent he back EMF from damaging the circuit during spin down.

Comment: You may want to put as much information as you have about the motors directly in your question so you can improve the quality of the question. Maybe then, people will stop down voting... It's a valid question.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser I edited the OP and added a lot of information.

Comment: Remember that 16 mA isn't a current that it's intentionally limited to--it's the current above which you may well be damaging the microcontroller. You should never use a gpio pin to drive much of anything, let alone a *motor*.

Comment: @TylerSelden I'm going to edit the question to see if we can make it better. If the edit doesn't make sense to you, then I think you can reject it. Let's see what happens.

Comment: A GPIO is simply too wimpy to drive even the smallest motor out there.  To get an idea of the motor specifications, get onto the Mabuchi Motors webpage and plow through their listings (they've made it hard, but you can if you're dilligent).  Find the motors that are the same measurements and that look the same -- your motor will almost certainly be one of them, or a Chinese knock-off.  You can guess at the motor's voltage rating by the batteries in the drone.

Answer (score 4):

With a current sourcing capacity of 16 mA, the GPIO pin is very likely unable to drive your motor sufficiently to make it turn freely.  You are also very likely overloading your Pi Zero.

When driving a motor you almost always want an external driver circuit.  An example of this might be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMtDbQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'd reduce R1 a bit, 470 or even 330R.

Comment: And don't put 12 V on those drone motors.

Comment: I missed the part about "drone motors".  I just see "DC motor".  It could be anything...